# What am I missing in putting an image on this canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am trying to draw on a canvas from an array of arrays that should initially be grey `#808080`. None of the permutations I am trying is changing that I have a full-screen canvas that is completely white.

I believe that I have missed some basic step in going from an imageData to a grey rectangle drawn on the screen.

What am I missing, or have I otherwise done wrong?

Thanks,

```js
;(function() {
  var context = null;
  var grid = [];
  var height = null;
  var image_data = null;
  var width = null;

  var draw = function() {
    var data = image_data.data;

    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index += 4) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) / width);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.floor(index / 4) * width);
      data[index] = grid[x][y][0];
      data[index + 1] = grid[x][y][1];
      data[index + 2] = grid[x][y][2];
    }

    image_data.data = data;
    context.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0);
  }

  var init = function() {
    height = jQuery(window).height();
    width = jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery('#container').html('<canvas id="map" height="' + height + '" width="' + width + '"></canvas>')
    context = document.getElementById('map').getContext('2d');
    image_data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    for (var outer = 0; outer < width; outer += 1) {
      grid[outer] = [];
      for (var inner = 0; inner < height; inner += 1) {
        grid[outer][inner] = [128, 128, 128];
      }
    }
  }

  var start_drawing = function() {
    draw();
    setTimeout(start_drawing, 1);
  };

  init();
  start_drawing();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: `image_data` is initialized with the canvas's content, yes ?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, but you'd still need 4 cells for each pixel, the last one equals 255 (alpha channel)

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov please don't recommend W3Schools. MDN is far more reliable, accurate and up to date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#art_gallery_example

Comment: And regarding the current TypeError, that's not how you convert from an index to coords. Instead do `remainder = index / width; y = Math.floor(remainder); x = Math.floor((remainder - width) * width)`, or just use a double loop `for(let x = 0; ...) for (let y = 0 ...) { ... index++; }};` probably still the clearest.